# RuntimeError: expected device cpu and dtype Byte but got device cpu and dtype Bool

Tags: pytorch, cpu, archlinux

As described in [the issue I opened](https://github.com/facebookresearch/inversecooking/issues/10), I get the following error when running the Pytorch [inverse-cooking](https://github.com/facebookresearch/inversecooking) model on CPU:

`RuntimeError: expected device cpu and dtype Byte but got device cpu and dtype Bool`

I have tried running the `demo.ipynb` file in both my laptop's Intel i7-4700HQ 8 threads and my desktop Ryzen 3700x. I was using Arch Linux on my laptop and Manjaro on my desktop.

The model works fine when I run it on Google Collabs GPU.

According to the `demo.ipynb` file the model should be able to run on CPU as well. Does anyone know if I have to tweak any parameters in order to make it work?

Comment: I think it's supposed to run with Pytorch 0.4 and you are probably using 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @iacolippo and in the comment session and [myDennisCode](https://github.com/facebookresearch/inversecooking/issues/10#issuecomment-537848360), the problem really was dependency versions. I had `torchvision==0.4.0` (which confused me) and `torch==1.2.0`.

To fix the problem, simply install `torch==0.4.1` and `torchvision==0.2.1`.